# Use npm install react native app, following error happens

Tags: react-native, npm-install

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@expo/ngrok-bin/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8
Installing dependencies using npm…

**npm ERR! cb() never called!**
Failed to install

Comment: Delete `node_modules` folder and try again.

Comment: You mean the 'node_modules' folder under the react native app folder created?

Comment: I have never seen the react native directory structure, but in react web, it is located at the project root. Cut and paste it somewhere if you are not comfortable deleting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by updating the npm version...